# Is there a way to know which promise fail in a `Promise.join`?

Tags: node.js, bluebird

In the following code (using the Bluebird library), is there a way, in case of error, to determine which of the promises failed?

```
Promise.join(User.getByName(username), User.getByKey(key), (user1, user2) => {
  //do operations
}).catch((error) => {
  //How to know which failed?
});
```

Both of these promises produce generic error messages on reject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. If you really  have to, you have to implement an error handler for each individually.

```
Promise.join(User.getByName(username)
    .catch(err => {throw new Error('error in getByName');}), 
  User.getByKey(key)
    .catch(err => {throw new Error('error in getByKey');}),
 (user1, user2) => {
  //do operations
}).catch((error) => {
  // error.message should now display origin of error
});
```

Comment: That's what I suspected.. Thank you